# HashMap to store data from other tables

Tags: java

i have those paths like this in array 'pc_list'

```
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]
```

and in other table 'retrieved_elements' i have

```
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/a = First 100 Words
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]/div[3] = by Roger Priddy
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/strong = $3.98
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong = $3.98
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/a/div[2] = First 100 Words
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/strong = $3.98
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[2] = First 100 Words
```

in my code , i check if table retrieved_elements contains a path from table pc_liste , and then if it exist i save the value after "=" 
for exemple the result that get is like this :

```
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]
 First 100 Words
 by Roger Priddy
 $3.98
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]
 $3.98
 First 100 Words
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]
 $3.98
 First 100 Words
```

but i want to save it in a map , in this step i found a problem , first this is my code :

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map_instances = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

pc_list = cp.checkSimilarity(retrieved_elements);
        for (int a = 0; a < pc_list.size(); a++) {
            String chemin_commun = pc_list.get(a);

           // System.out.println(chemin_commun);
            for (int b = 0; b < retrieved_elements.size(); b++) {

                String chemin_complet = retrieved_elements.get(b);

                if (chemin_complet.contains(chemin_commun)) {

                    chemin_complet = chemin_complet.split("=")[1];
                    inst_value.add(chemin_complet);
                    //System.out.println(chemin_complet);
                      map_instances.put(chemin_commun, inst_value);

                }
            }
            }
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> item : map_instances.entrySet()) {
            String key = item.getKey();
          System.out.println(item);
        }
```

but result of looping the map is like this :

```
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]=[ First 100 Words,  by Roger Priddy,  $3.98,  $3.98,  First 100 Words,  $3.98,  First 100 Words]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]=[ First 100 Words,  by Roger Priddy,  $3.98,  $3.98,  First 100 Words,  $3.98,  First 100 Words]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]=[ First 100 Words,  by Roger Priddy,  $3.98,  $3.98,  First 100 Words,  $3.98,  First 100 Words]
```

instead of being like  :

```
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[9]/div[2]=[ First 100 Words,  by Roger Priddy,  $3.98]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]=[ $3.98,  First 100 Words]
body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]=[$3.98,  First 100 Words]
```

Comment: It looks like you're not initializing `inst_value` anywhere. Please note that when you `put` a value in a map, it puts the reference, not a copy of the value.

Comment: i dont think it's a prb of initialization :/

Comment: Yes, it most certainly is: you keep adding values to the same list, and putting a reference to the same list in all your map entries.

Comment: so please how can i , store for each instance a set of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to have a different list object in each map entry.

The way you are doing this, you have a single list object, and you add all the values to that single object, and then put that single object as the value of all the mappings.

So forget about `inst_value`. Instead, when you find the first value for a certain `chemin_commun`, you create a new list and put it in the map. And the next time you find a value, you simply add to that new list you created. This makes sure that each `chemin_commun` has its own list, not a list shared between all.

So let's look at this piece of code:

```
if (chemin_complet.contains(chemin_commun)) {

    chemin_complet = chemin_complet.split("=")[1];
    inst_value.add(chemin_complet);
    //System.out.println(chemin_complet);
    map_instances.put(chemin_commun, inst_value);

}
```

Change it to:

```
if (chemin_complet.contains(chemin_commun)) {

    ArrayList<String> currentList = map_instances.get(chemin_commun);

    if ( currentList == null ) {
         // This is the first time we see this chemin_commun, so
         // Create a new list for it and put it in the map.
         currentList = new ArrayList<>();
         map_instances.put(chemin_commun, currentList );
    }

    // At this point currentList is never null. It is the specific list
    // that is mapped by the current chemin_commun. So add the value
    // to this list
    chemin_complet = chemin_complet.split("=")[1];
    currentList.add(chemin_complet);

}
```

---

A few general Java notes:

- Variable and method names should not contain underscores. Java has code conventions. In short:

  - Type names (names of classes, interfaces, enums) should start with an uppercase letter and have a new uppercase letter at the beginning of every word, for example `MyParser` or `VeryLongClassName`.
  - Method and variable names should start with a lowercase letter and have an uppercase letter at the beginning of every new word. For example `cheminCommun`, `cheminComplet` etc.
  - Constants (`final static` fields or enum constants) are all in uppercase and they are the only ones where underscores separate words: `BASE_SIZE`, `PROPERTY_NAME` etc.)
- Program to the interface, not to the class. That is, don't declare your variables as `ArrayList` but as `List`, not as `HashMap` but as `Map`. And then only assign a specific class to them. So your map should actually be declared:

  ```
  Map<String,List<String>> mapInstances = new HashMap<>();
  ```

  The declaration is with the interface `Map` (and `List`), the actual object is a `HashMap`. And then you'll declare `currentList` as `List<String>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. If in the future you want to use a `LinkedList` or a `TreeMap`, it will be easier to change the code.

Comment: thanks realskeptic , it's clear now ur explination (y)